# Capturing the texte being written in an input box with Flutter and send it to a TensorFlow Lite model in real time

Tags: firebase, flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I'm planning an app where a TensorFlow Lite model on device would analyse the text being written by the user in the input box and provide a feedback in real time.

The app would be developed with Flutter for iOS, Android, Web and Desktop.

I'm not used to that and I would like to evaluate how complicated (or not) it would be with this option. The other option being JavaScript with React Native.

Basically, TensorFlow would compare the text with a list of expressions and send informations to the frontend if some patterns are used.

For performances reasons, I guess it is better to update the TensorFlow model at the end of each word, rather than at each character.

I'm looking for code samples with examples of this type of process. Something smart and optimized.

Do you have some examples in mind?

Thanks

Comment: You can find some flutter sample apps of firebase_ml_vision here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/example